# How to NOT store credentials for WPA enterprise?

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, password

I'm connecting to some enterprise wireless network (eduroam).

The thing is that it saves the User/Password in the wireless settings, anyone can click 'Show password' and see my university account password.

What I want is that it prompts me everytime the credentials inputs when I try to connect to the network and don't save it under the 'settings' page.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Thanks

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: By "anyone" you mean "anyone who can log in to your Linux account"?

Comment: @grawity yes, I managed to change the options thanks to pomsky

Comment: Related on unix.se: [Connect to WiFi without storing password (Raspbian)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/242811/47326). This was also eduroam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're entering your credentials while connecting for the first time, click on the symbol in the "*Password*" field. A pop-up should appear. Select "*Ask for this password every time*".

[image]

Comment: That's a sneaky place where to put those options ! (and also I have the 'users' icon instead of the question mark) Thanks for the tip, it worked

Comment: @toto 'users' icon will turn into a question mark after you select "Ask for this password every time" ; )

Comment: I don't get that window above upon connecting to a network, and, for some reason, selecting "Ask for this password every time" in the settings greys out the Apply button when I try to...well, apply the setting.

Comment: @MonatheMonad Most probably it's greyed out due to some other incomplete/wrongly-filled field(s).

Comment: I'm not sure what other fields there are that would be incomplete or wrongly filled. On my end, it's just two drop-down boxes and a checkbox (Security, Password, and Show password).